SQL - Querying Data Within Certain Time Ranges
I'm trying to create a table called "Stats" that employees use a business application where they perform searches and projects on it. I'm trying to answer the following questions with the SQL queries:

How many different employees used the business application within a certain time range?

How many searches were performed within a certain time range?

What was the average search time within this time range?


Here's the table:
CREATE TABLE Stats (
  employee_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  number_of_employees INT,
  search VARCHAR(50),
  number_of_results INT,
  start_time timestamp with time zone,
  completion_time timestamp with time zone
)

INSERT INTO Stats (employee_id, number_of_employees, search,    number_of_results, start_time, completion_time)
  VALUES (001, 125, “organization”, 2000, 2020-04-18 12:13:21.101+00, 2020-04-18 12:13:26.53+00)
INSERT INTO Stats (employee_id, number_of_employees, search, number_of_results, start_time, completion_time)
  VALUES (005, 127, “organization”, 2000, 2020-04-18 12:14:32.877+00, 2020-04-18 12:16:53.43+00)

I tried to query the distinct number of employees by creating parameters to find the needed info within the time range, but I keep getting errors and I don't know why? Here's what I have:
    SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(employee_id), COUNT("search"),
    AVG(number_of_results), COUNT(*), start_time, completion_time
    FROM Stats
    WHERE employee_id =
    (
    SELECT employee_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "search")
    FROM Stats
    );
    CREATE PROCEDURE timerange(
    StartDATE = date(start_time),
    EndDATE = date(completion_time),
    StartTIME = timestamp(start_time),
    EndTIME = timestamp(completion_time)
    DATEDifference DATE = EndDATE - StartDATE
    TimeDifference TIME = ENDTIME - StartTIME
    CertainRange = CONCAT(DateDifference || TimeDifference) AS
    CertainTimeRange
    )
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
    BEGIN
    (SELECT CertainRange
    FROM Stats
    WHERE start_time >= StartDATE 
       AND completion_time >= EndDATE 
       AND completion_time >= EndDATE 
       AND completion_time >= EndTIME
    ORDER BY employee_id ASC LIMIT 2);
    END;
    $$;

I get an error when I use the time function. I'm not able to grab the users, "search" results, and the average search time. I'm not quite sure if I need to alter the table to create a new column that does a DATEDIFF between the date parameters in order to hold the certain time range. I'm also not sure how to subtract the difference for timestamps. Please help, I'm really stuck here.

Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific in several ways.)

I'm using PostgreSQL

Why don't you use the range data types for ranges?

And subtract sounds like -. It's just math
